# SwiftUI: SF Symbol distortion when using `Image` directly vs via `UIImage`

Tags: swiftui, uiimage

With the following SwiftUI code

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      VStack {
        Text("Proportional")
        Image(systemName: "bookmark")
      }

      VStack {
        Text("Skewed")
        Image(uiImage: UIImage(systemName: "bookmark")!)
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}
```

The image that is instantiated directly with `Image(systemName:)` is rendered correctly, while the one instantiated with `Image(uiImage:)` is stretched horizontally, as seen here

[image: attached image].

Is there a view modifier that I could use that would fix this? I've already tried various permutations of `.aspectRatio()`, `.resizable()`, `.scaledToFit()`, etc. to no avail.

Comment: Why would you need to do this as it seems redundant to create the  using `Image(uiImage: )` just to pass in a `UIImage(systemName: )`

Comment: The model/API I’m working with only returns `UIImage`s, which can be from multiple sources, such as an asset catalog, pulled from the network, or instantiated from a SF Symbol. Refactoring the API is not in the cards at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that this is a bug with current SwiftUI that has been fixed in Xcode 15 beta that was released at WWCD '23, because the behavior is no longer manifesting itself in the beta version of Xcode.